# Rational Functional Test Object Finder doesn't work for a desktop application on win 8.1

Tags: rft

I am new to RFT(Rational Functional Test). I try to add/update the test object of a desktop application, but when I use any selection method (drag hand...), nothing happens. I have added the application. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of RFT are you using? You said  "Nothing happens"  when you click on the object finder  so I think that issue was addressed in a recent version of RFT so let's give RFT  8606  a try.

Comment: Hi, I used RFT 8.2.1 which is the only version we bought. It's working fine on a previous win 7 machine, and I try to set up on a win8 machine, it doesn't work anymore. I don't know the previous setting exactly. Do you know which I may miss in this case.

Comment: Looks like an issue that we had seen  on Windows 8. Could you try this ..  once you open the insert  object/vp wizard   , before you click on the object finder button    move/drag  the window a little   to change its position  and then click on the object finder button ..

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. Which version you are using? It seems RFT support win 8 since 8.3.

Comment: I am using  8606 , may  be you should try to use the latest or 8.3 atleast.